Export VSCode terminal output to separate file
I am running a node.js script that outputs data directly to the terminal in VS Code. I need to share this data with colleagues, but copying and pasting from the terminal into a document is a formatting nightmare and would not be readable at all.
I figured there would be a simple way to export the terminal output to a file extension that I can share, but I'm finding zero options for this in my research.
I'm on MacOS and using the built in terminal in VSCode. Is anyone aware of a way to export the terminal output to a file that I can share?
Thanks in advance.

type npm run script_name >filename in the terminal

I was able to write node script_name > filename.txt and that worked to create a new text file with the terminal output.
